# HBase: Specify VERSIONS while creating table using Java API

Tags: hbase

I know we can do it from hbase shell in the following way:

```
create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}
```

I could not find any corresponding option in `HTableDesctiptor` in the Java API. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max versions, and other ttl type settings, is specified per column family.  So the max versions is on the [HColumnDescriptor](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor.html).

Answer (score 4):

I leave here a sample code based on your example as reference.

```
HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor("t1");
HColumnDescriptor cd = new HColumnDescriptor("f1");
cd.setMaxVersions(5);
descriptor.addFamily(cd);
```