# How to turn off HBase table versioning?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

If I insert two rows with the same key at different time HBase will save the tow rows under one key row key but in two different versions. However, what if I want to HBase not to save a seconds version ? just override the first or just don't save it at all ? Is there any table configurations to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 0):

See this link. It gives a shell and java pointer:

[HBase: Specify VERSIONS while creating table using Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508499/hbase-specify-versions-while-creating-table-using-java-api)

I believe Versioning is specified at the column level. This can be set in the shell or in the Java API

Answer (score -1):

You can do it, by just put the version as 1 at the time of table creation so you will have always latest version of your column family.